# Delphi Package: Systools - I Need It!

Tags: delphi, components

Any chance someone out there still has SysTools 3 Components (S303_D60.bpl)
It's was supposedly used at some point on the project I'm working on, but I can't find locally or on the web.

Thanks,
-nomad311

Answer (score 2):

Turbo Power released their component suite to the community some time ago, you will probably find the source code for SysTools on SourceForge....in fact let me google.....

[This looks like it...](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/)

Comment: Already tried the google thing, but that verison isn't available at SF. I did ask the developers to make previous releases available ...so we'll see. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

The converted to Delphi 2009/2010 version is also available on the [songbeamer](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/) Delphi website.

Comment: Since I am maintaining a damn complicated app that was written serveral years back, we're not going to upgrade it. So I am praying that I won't have to upgrade the components and possibly introduce bugs. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Systools has been open-sourced for quite a few years at this point and versions 4.03 and 4.04 are [now available at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/).  I was able to download the latest version from SourceForge and get it installed into XE4.  The zip file that I downloaded had packages for 2007 through XE2 and also XE5, so I had to create XE4.  I copied the XE2 folder and it's contents and re-labelled it to XE4.  I then opened the Delphi project file.  I right-clicked and then chose "View as Text" each .dpk file in order to change XE2 to XE4 in the description and then saved.   I then re-compiled the whole thing.  In XE4 be sure to go to "Tools -> Options -> Delphi Options -> Libraries" to set the "dcp" and "bpl" output folder choices.  This is where the compiled files will be stored.  I moved these folders to a "Delphi Libraries -> Systools -> 4.04" folder and then added the bpl folder to the above "Libraries" path.  I then used "Component -> Install Packages..." to install the packages by navigating to 
the bpl folder and choosing each package in turn.  The Systools option with individual components showed up on the Delphi tool bar.

Comment: You *did* see that the post you responded to was dated 2009, right? And that it didn't ask for installation instructions? And that it was asking for a **specific** version of SysTools that wasn't available via SourceForge?